# I add a new property in bpy.types.Material and how to dynamically change the node numbers in material?

Tags: python

I add a new property in bpy.types.Material:

```
bpy.types.Material.mat_settings = PointerProperty(type=MaterialSettings)
```

And how to dynamically change the node numbers in material for the addon? By using update or get/set? I was not clear.

```
def get_nodes_num(self, context):
    obj = context.active_object
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        mymat = obj.data.materials[0]
        self['nodenum'] =len(mymat.node_tree.nodes)

class MaterialSettings(PropertyGroup):
    # FOR Material SETTINGS
    nodenum : IntProperty(
        name = "NodeNum",
        description = "total nodes number",
        default = 0,
        update = get_nodes_num
        )
```

I print the value of mat.mat_dim_settings.nodenum which is always 0.When I tried to change nodenum value on the addon, it will show the correct value, otherwise always at 0.

Comment: Why do you need a new property in `bpy.types.Material`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're way overcomplicating the problem here.

I suggest you take advantage of python's monkeypatching capabilities to add an helper getter method. If your endgoal is only to have an easy access to the number of nodes of a material you shouldn't build a separate property that you will have to keep in sync every time you change the material node tree. That would be introducing a redundancy which is bad programmatically.

```
bpy.types.Material.get_nodes_number = lambda mat: len(mat.node_tree.nodes) if mat.node_tree else 0

mat = bpy.data.materials["Material"]
print(mat.get_nodes_number())
```

Or if you don't want to monkeypatch, use a global function.

```
def get_nodes_number(mat):
    return len(mat.node_tree.nodes) if mat.node_tree else 0

mat = bpy.data.materials["Material"]
print(get_nodes_number(mat))
```

Comment: Indeed helpful! Thanks!